# Swift: AnyClass is not a type

Tags: swift

I'm trying to access an application delegate from SDK that does not know the class name of the application delegate. I mean that my SDK doesn't know what class will be an application delegate in a basic project. So I find a class that conforms to the protocol UIApplicationDelegate.

```
    let numberOfClasses: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.alloc(0)
    let classes = objc_copyClassList(numberOfClasses)
    var appDelegateClass: AnyClass? = nil

    for i in 0...Int(numberOfClasses.memory) {
        if class_conformsToProtocol(classes[i], UIApplicationDelegate.self) {
            appDelegateClass = classes[i]
        }
    }
```

But the result has "type" "AnyClass?". The following code results getting an error "'applicationDelegateClass' is not a type":

```
    if let applicationDelegateClass = appDelegateClass {
        if let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? applicationDelegateClass.self { }
    }
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: Why you are not calling method like : let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `UIApplication.shared.delegate` *is* the application delegate, no matter what its class name is. – You cannot conditionally cast to a *variable* class type.

Comment: Because my SDK doesn't know what class will be an application delegate in a basic project.

Comment: Do you need the application delegate or its class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually shouldn't use the specific application delegate class. The right code:

```
if let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as? UIApplicationDelegate {}
```